# CEFSharp Ofscreen and standard WPF browser in same app

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I need to use CEFSharp offscreen and standard Browser inside the same application... but I'm facing issue in initialization. I'm using something like that:

```
OffScreenBrowser = new biCefBrowser(true);
await OffScreenBrowser.InitializeBrowser(HTMLHome);

BiBrowser = new biCefBrowser(false);
await BiBrowser.InitializeBrowser(HTMLHome);
SupportWindow.RootGrid.Children.Add(BiBrowser.WpfBrowser);
```

But everything hangs.

I've already tried to split objects and force single CEF.Initialize

Comment: Already asked at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/discussions/4590 Please just ask your question once and wait for a reply before posting in multiple places.